# Resize the UIViewController View

Tags: xcode

I am new in iPhone/Ipad Application development and Just learning the UIViewController, UIView etc with Xcode and while using uiviewcontroller want  to resize but my tricks logic are not working. please let me know if you have any Idea with this.

Thanks

Comment: your question is not very clear. How/when are you trying to resize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your are looking like this.

```
(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
menuView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgground.jpg"]];// i used 1 view name is menuView
UIViewController *menu =[[UIViewController alloc] init];menu.view = menuView;
[menu setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
[self presentModalViewController:menu animated:YES];
[menu release];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After resize try this code

```
UIViewController* view = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController: view animated: NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO];
[view release];
```